# Count the number of days in (long) weekends in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
DAYS7 <- c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')   
DAYS <- rep(DAYS7,5)   
A <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)   
B <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,2)   
DESIRED_OUTPUT <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)   
dataframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(DAYS, A, B, DESIRED_OUTPUT))
```

If it's a working day, the corresponding cell in *column A* equals zero. If it is holiday, *column A* shows 1. (Note that there might be long weekends, e.g. row 12, row 19, rows 22-23!) *Column B* is essentially a cummulative sum of *column A*, with the condition that whenever a zero occurs, the cummulation resets. What I intend to do is to calculate the length of each weekend (in days) and then print the result in an additional column like this (see column *DESIRED_OUTPUT*):
[image]

In Excel it is relatively easy…
[image]

…but I'm struggling to find a proper solution in R. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part is to define one week which is group of 0's followed by group of 1's. We can do that using `rle`, once that is done we can use that as a grouping variable in `ave` and count number of 1's in each group using `sum`.

```
with(dataframe, ave(A, with(rle(A == 0), rep(cumsum(values), lengths)), FUN = sum))
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Since `B` is cumulative sum of `A`, we can use that as well here and count the `max` value in group.

```
with(dataframe, ave(B, with(rle(A == 0), rep(cumsum(values), lengths)), FUN = max))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` way...

```
library(tidyverse)


DAYS7 <- c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')   
DAYS <- rep(DAYS7,5)   
A <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)   
B <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,2)   
DESIRED_OUTPUT <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)   
dataframe <- data.frame(DAYS, A, B, DESIRED_OUTPUT)  


dataframe %>%
    mutate(beginningOfWeek = (B - lag(B)) < 0) %>%
    mutate(beginningOfWeek = replace_na(beginningOfWeek, TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(week_nr = cumsum(beginningOfWeek)) %>%
    group_by(week_nr) %>%
    mutate(desired_output = max(B))

   DAYS          A     B DESIRED_OUTPUT beginningOfWeek week_nr desired_output
   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl> <lgl>             <int>          <dbl>
 1 Monday        0     0              2 TRUE                  1              2
 2 Tuesday       0     0              2 FALSE                 1              2
 3 Wednesday     0     0              2 FALSE                 1              2
 4 Thursday      0     0              2 FALSE                 1              2
 5 Friday        0     0              2 FALSE                 1              2
 6 Saturday      1     1              2 FALSE                 1              2
 7 Sunday        1     2              2 FALSE                 1              2
 8 Monday        0     0              3 TRUE                  2              3
 9 Tuesday       0     0              3 FALSE                 2              3
10 Wednesday     0     0              3 FALSE                 2              3
11 Thursday      0     0              3 FALSE                 2              3
12 Friday        1     1              3 FALSE                 2              3
13 Saturday      1     2              3 FALSE                 2              3
14 Sunday        1     3              3 FALSE                 2              3
15 Monday        0     0              5 TRUE                  3              5
16 Tuesday       0     0              5 FALSE                 3              5
17 Wednesday     0     0              5 FALSE                 3              5
18 Thursday      0     0              5 FALSE                 3              5
19 Friday        1     1              5 FALSE                 3              5
20 Saturday      1     2              5 FALSE                 3              5
21 Sunday        1     3              5 FALSE                 3              5
22 Monday        1     4              5 FALSE                 3              5
23 Tuesday       1     5              5 FALSE                 3              5
24 Wednesday     0     0              3 TRUE                  4              3
25 Thursday      0     0              3 FALSE                 4              3
26 Friday        1     1              3 FALSE                 4              3
27 Saturday      1     2              3 FALSE                 4              3
28 Sunday        1     3              3 FALSE                 4              3
29 Monday        0     0              2 TRUE                  5              2
30 Tuesday       0     0              2 FALSE                 5              2
31 Wednesday     0     0              2 FALSE                 5              2
32 Thursday      0     0              2 FALSE                 5              2
33 Friday        0     0              2 FALSE                 5              2
34 Saturday      1     1              2 FALSE                 5              2
35 Sunday        1     2              2 FALSE                 5              2
```

So, I didn't remove the intermediate columns, so that it's clearer, what they are actually for.